# VLC won't open video files from a secondary internal hard disk

Tags: permissions, vlc

I have installed Ubuntu 16.10 on a 120GB hard disk (sda) and I have a secondary internal hard disk 500GB (sdc) which has nothing else but a folder with video files in it.

When I try to open a video with VLC on that sdc drive I get this error:

```
File reading failed:
VLC could not open the file "/media/"username"/"hardisksdcname"/Videos/"videofoldername"/"videoname".avi" (Permission denied).
Your input can't be opened:
VLC is unable to open the MRL 'file:///media/"username"/"harddisksdcname"/Videos/"videofoldername"/"videoname".avi'. Check the log for details.
```

The permissions are "read and write" for all (root and others).

When I copy the video to my desktop and then try to play it with VLC (from the desktop source copy) it works but when I try to strictly play it from my SDC hard drive this error appears.

I don't know where VLC stores its log file.

This is how my devices show up:

```
NAME   MAJ:MIN RM   SIZE RO TYPE MOUNTPOINT
loop1    7:1    0   115M  0 loop /snap/vlc/4  ***<--whats that?***
sdb      8:16   0 447,1G  0 disk 
sr0     11:0    1   1,1G  0 rom  /media/papajo/Ubuntu 15.10 amd64
loop2    7:2    0   228K  0 loop /snap/htop/68
loop0    7:0    0    76M  0 loop /snap/core/714
sdc      8:32   0 465,8G  0 disk 
└─sdc1   8:33   0 465,8G  0 part 
sda      8:0    0 119,2G  0 disk 
├─sda2   8:2    0 102,8G  0 part /
├─sda3   8:3    0    16G  0 part [SWAP]
└─sda1   8:1    0   512M  0 part /boot/efi
sr1     11:1    1   1,5G  0 rom  /media/papajo/Ubuntu 16.10 amd64
```

Comment: Have you tried a different video player such as Videos?

Comment: the default video player can access those files but I want vlc to do it.. on my previous installation it worked fine...

Comment: Oh well,the only other thing I can think of is to remove and reinstall VLC,but you probably tried that.Sorry,I don't use VLC;so that's the limit of my (Ha)expertise.

Comment: Nothing worked for me: reinstalling via snap, moving video folder to home directory, changing ownership to myself and permissions to 777, and what not! Also, I did not want to reinstall using apt as I wanted to use 2 package managers for my system. I came across [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/a/1238219/21359) with help of which I understood recent versions of VLC snaps (VLC 3.0.12.1 on freshly installed Ubuntu 20.04) only has the "home" interface - not the generic "personal-files" interface, which restricts it from using hidden files.

Comment: I tried these steps and it didn't work. snap applications are limited to user's home directories. instead, I mounted the partition as /media/$USER/part and did a symbolic link from .part to /media/$USER/part

Answer (score 22):

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

Then install it using APT:

```
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

Comment: This is a copy of @doug answer above ... just without useful commentaries.

Comment: `sudo snap install --classic vlc` didn't work for me. I installed it using apt and only after that was it loading files outside of $HOME

Comment: I have a clear installation of Ubuntu 18.04 and I had the same problem reported in the question. This solution worked perfectly for me and solved the problem of not accessible devices from VLC without using snap packages.

Comment: Craisy simple solution that works)

Comment: +1 On ubuntu 20.10, I tried using `vlc` to play a file in `/tmp`, and it wouldn't do it (`cannot open file /tmp/foo.mp4 (no such file or directory)`, and so I removed the snap, and re-installed w/ `sudo snap install --classic vlc` but it reported: `Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap vlc` (obviously still didn't work).  Installing via `sudo apt install vlc` fixed it. Caveat: apt installed slightly older `3.0.11.1` and snap installs newer `3.0.12.1`, but at least the repo version actually works.

Comment: Works on Ubuntu 20.04 like a charm!

Answer (score 18):

If you're using the snap vlc, by default it'll be confined. To get around that, remove it:

```
sudo snap remove vlc
```

Then install from the command line:

```
sudo snap install --classic  vlc
```

This will allow browsing & loading files outside of $HOME

**Please note:** that on 16.04 with current snapd package this is no longer needed, vlc can browse mounted volumes, obviously same is true for 18.04.

`--classic` is basically the old `--devmode` option.

Though atm there seems no way to use hardware decoding with snaps, if that matters to you...

Comment: Still doesnt work... what matters to me is to have it the old way... I dont know what snaps are why are they good I dont want them or have any use for them every program that uses snaps is problematic for me... and they make a mess I have like 10 "snaps" partitions of a few MB each which I never created...

Comment: Then remove the snap & install the repo vlc that's packaged as a .deb

Comment: how?  (not only how to remove the snap version of vlc but the snaps themselves too ) because sudo snap remove vlc doesnt do the trick

Comment: What do you mean 'doesn't do the trick'?,  run the command, copy & paste the results to a pastebin or just ask on ubuntu forums which is more suitable to interactive problem solving.

Comment: Thank you. This worked for me. Could you please explain the difference between the two versions?

Comment: This is not working on Ubuntu 16.04 with VLC 3 and VLC 4, it cannot play files on other hard drives. It seems I have to use a .deb sadly.

Comment: Vlc no longer needs that --classic option, can browse mounted media in 16.04 & 18.04. If you find differently then update to latest snapd.

Comment: I still have the same problem with Ubuntu 18.04!

Comment: The snap vlc wouldn't play a file in `/tmp`, terribly annoying (this is Ubuntu 20.10). So I tried: `sudo snap install --classic vlc` but it reported: `Warning: flag --classic ignored for strictly confined snap vlc` (and still same problem, of course).  Installing via `sudo apt install vlc` fixed it, albeit `apt` installs a slightly older (but working!) version of `vlc`.

Comment: Did not work on Ubuntu 20.04, using apt-get works!

Comment: This worked on Ubuntu 24.04. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, I had to change ownership of the video file from root to the user I was logged on as.  Then the file would play.  I am using Ubuntu 20.04, installed VLC via snap.

Answer (score -1):

Without uninstalling and reinstalling VLC, you can see or listen to your local media files by moving the audio/video file to `/home/<your-name>/snap/vlc/<example-audio-file>`

Comment: idk if this works but I am pretty sure you are missing the username  /home/<username>/snap

Comment: I didn't miss it, I did put it in the text box provided to answer the question. Somehow when the answer was posted it ended up with two forward slashes where in between those I put the username.  This is how I put it. /home/<your-username>/snap/vlc/<your-media-file>.