# Cannot install VLC on Ubuntu 17.04

Tags: vlc

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
 vlc : Depends: vlc-plugin-video-output (= 2.2.4-13) but it is not going to be installed
E: Unable to correct problems, you have held broken packages.
```

This is what I am running into. To be honest, I'm new to  Ubuntu and to Linux in general so any help would be very much appreciated.

```
W: The repository 'zppa.launchpad.net/ed10vi86/video/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
W: The repository 'zppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu zesty Release' does not have a Release file.
N: Data from such a repository can't be authenticated and is therefore potentially dangerous to use.
N: See apt-secure(8) manpage for repository creation and user configuration details.
E: Failed to fetch zppa.launchpad.net/ed10vi86/video/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-i386/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Failed to fetch zppa.launchpad.net/videolan/stable-daily/ubuntu/dists/zesty/main/binary-amd64/Packages  404  Not Found
E: Some index files failed to download. They have been ignored, or old ones used instead.
```

Comment: You should check the output of `sudo apt-get update`, something is wrong with the repositories.

Comment: thats what im seeing from that   put a z infront of the links it wouldnt let me post them lol

Comment: Is that all, or have you copied just the end? You should have a lot more output with standard repositories of main, restricted, updated, universe, multiverse, etc. If that's all, open Software Properties and select a mirror close to your location. https://askubuntu.com/a/37825/20054

Comment: https://pastebin.com/cmgtpSBT

Comment: thats the whole output

Comment: Let us see your sources list: `cat /etc/apt/sources.list`.  Also, a look at the https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/stable-daily reveals zero packages for 17.04. I'd recommend removing it with `sudo ppa-purge ppa:videolan/stable-daily`.

Answer (score 1):

You can install VLC with `snap`. It seems to fit since you have a dependency problem.

```
snap install vlc
```

Edit :

As pointed in [this thread](https://askubuntu.com/questions/875421/vlc-wont-open-video-files-from-a-secondary-interal-hard-disk), if your files are stored on a dedicated drive you may want to install VLC with the `--classic` flag.

```
snap install --classic vlc
```

I've just tried without `--classic` and ran into permission problems accessing files from my second hard drive in VLC.
The flag made the trick. 
Thought it could be useful to point.