# Packages not updated after adding ppa

Tags: ppa, vlc, launchpad

I'm trying to upgrade vlc to 3.0

```
sudo add-apt-repository ppa:videolan/master-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install vlc
```

The repo was added fine, as well as the update but it just says it's already in the latest version (2.2.2). Also searching vlc only list version 2.2.2.
I know this question has been asked multiple times already but I can't still find a solution.

My machine is a minimal installation of Ubuntu 16.04.3.

Comment: 2.2.6 is the newest version. 2.2.2 maybe the newest available for 16.04. since upgradeing to 2.2.6 also requires updating dependencies

Comment: Oh, I thought it's 3.0.0 as listed here: https://launchpad.net/~videolan/+archive/ubuntu/master-daily?field.series_filter=xenial

Comment: hmmm, vlc list 2.2.6 as newest

Comment: I ran into some trouble when installing VLC as well. As describe in [this conversation](https://askubuntu.com/questions/919179/cannot-install-vlc-on-ubuntu-17-04/939362#939362) I finaly just went for `snap install --classic vlc`.

Comment: Thanks for your reply guys but I looked for alternatives and find smplayer fit my needs. It has ugly interface though.