# dotfile failed to read file

Tags: command-line, github, hidden-files

When I create a file without a dot (hidden) and use `gh`, (Github cli), to create a gist, it works.
But when I change it to a hidden file it fails to read a file.

```
# I can create a gist with a normal file.
shinichi@shinichi-Ubuntu:~$ gh gist create /home/shinichi/testing-gh
- Creating gist testing-gh
✓ Created gist testing-gh
https://gist.github.com/b2cd617f8cf35dc54986f5855ae92b1f

# checking permissions
shinichi@shinichi-Ubuntu:~$ ls -al ~/testing-gh 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 shinichi shinichi 42 Jul 30 08:40 /home/shinichi/testing-gh

# Changing the file to a hidden one
shinichi@shinichi-Ubuntu:~$ mv testing-gh ./.testing-gh

# Creating a Gist fails
shinichi@shinichi-Ubuntu:~$ gh gist create /home/shinichi/.testing-gh
failed to collect files for posting: failed to read file /home/shinichi/.testing-gh: open /home/shinichi/.testing-gh: permission denied

# checking the permission
shinichi@shinichi-Ubuntu:~$ ls -al ~/.testing-gh 
-rw-rw-r-- 1 shinichi shinichi 42 Jul 30 08:40 /home/shinichi/.testing-gh
```

This works on macOS, but not Ubuntu.
Why is it? How can I fix the problem?
How can I make a dotfiles Gist on Ubuntu?

Comment: How did you install the GitHub CLI? Is it a snap?

Comment: Yes. $ which gh
/snap/bin/gh

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How to make snaps access hidden files and folders in ~/home?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238211/how-to-make-snaps-access-hidden-files-and-folders-in-home)

Comment: Looks like the GitHub CLI snap is defined to not be able access hidden files and directories. Probably only GitHub can change that.

Answer (score 1):

Thank you for [the link](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1238211/how-to-make-snaps-access-hidden-files-and-folders-in-home).

So I removed the snap gh:

```
sudo snap remove gh
sudo rm -rf ~/snap/gh
```

Then downloaded a Debian package from https://github.com/cli/cli/releases/tag/v1.13.1, then click to install it.

I'm going to uninstall all snap packages and replace them with `sudo apt install`.
I must say I don't like the snap.